# Swift 3: How to remove the grey areas of the screenshot of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, screenshot

I've facing problems in removing the grey areas from the screenshot of the tableview.

This is the output when I tried to screenshot a `UITableView` (I actually hide some of the `tableViewCell` that's not needed, probably that's why area appears grey colour)

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you very much! :)

**Answer**

I found the solution by using @kishan and @Sneak's answer.
As I've screenshot my `UITableView` programmatically, I just changed the view's and tableview's `backgroundColor` to white in the codes.

```
func screenshot() -> UIImage{
    var image = UIImage();
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tableView.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    // save initial values
    let savedContentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    let savedFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    let savedBackgroundColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor

    // reset offset to top left point
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0);
    // set frame to content size
    self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.contentSize.width, height: self.tableView.contentSize.height);
    // set background to white
   //-->// self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // make temp view with scroll view content size
    // a workaround for issue when image on ipad was drawn incorrectly
    let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.contentSize.width, height: self.tableView.contentSize.height));

    //-->//tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // save superview
    let tempSuperView = self.tableView.superview
    // remove scrollView from old superview
    self.tableView.removeFromSuperview()
    // and add to tempView
    tempView.addSubview(self.tableView)

    // render view
    // drawViewHierarchyInRect not working correctly
    tempView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    // and get image
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!;

    // and return everything back
    tempView.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
    tempSuperView?.addSubview(self.tableView)

    // restore saved settings
    self.tableView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    self.tableView.frame = savedFrame;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = savedBackgroundColor

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image
}
```

Comment: tableView.backgroundColor maybe?

Comment: Change the y of your table view.

Comment: @User511 what do you mean by 'y'?

Comment: In storyboard -> file's owner of your view controller -> `Adjust scrollview edge insets` is ticked? If yes please untick and then check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this hope its work :)

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque = NO;
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: do you have this in swift 3? :)

Comment: self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray  and same for all :) and you must override the following method override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

Comment: I can't do this as some of my cells' backgroundColor is red for other purposes.

Comment: OK then only change your background color. and instead of cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear you can cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor for your cells

Comment: is it possible to remove the grey areas completely instead of the changing backgroundColor? Because my cells has more than one color if you refer to my screenshot.

Comment: tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()   Try it

Answer (score 0):

Here what you see gray color is the footerview of tableview, so you can make that view nil or initialize it like this

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

This may solve your issue...